# Split a string having atleast one special character like - # and a space as well

Tags: java, regex

I will have words like this

```
String text = [ name abc ]
String text = [ name # abcd]
String text = [ name - abcd]
String text = [ name  abcde    ]
```

i want to split these words to get names as abc, abcd, abcde

A delimitter here can be onlyspaces , spaces#spaces , spaces-spaces and nospace.

I have this regex to match

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\[\s*name\s*(-|#)\s*[a-z0-9]+\s*\]",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String subseq = matcher.group();
        String extractName = subseq.split("(-|#|\\s*)", 2)[1].replaceAll("]", "").trim();
        }
```

This code fails for [name mynameisDON] however it is working for [name : abc]

i want to know what regex to pass to this split function, so that i can acheive what i want.

Comment: How about deleting all special characters and then simply splitting on spaces?

Comment: How can "nospace" be a delimiter? If there is nothing there, there is no delimiter.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://regex101.com/r/rBcpaS/1

Comment: What do you mean by [*"For me editing the current matcher is a constraint"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58715818/split-a-string-having-atleast-one-special-character-like-and-a-space-as-well#comment103726047_58716297)? What can you edit in the code above?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private static void test(String text) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[\\s*(?i:name)\\s+(?:[#-]\\s+)?([^\\]\\s]+)\\s*\\]").matcher(text);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("name: '" + m.group(1) + "'");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid: '" + text + "'");
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
test("[ name abc ]");
test("[ name # abcd]");
test("[ name - abcd]");
test("[ name  abcde    ]");
test("[ name : abcd]");
test("[ name#abcd]");
```

*Output*

```
name: 'abc'
name: 'abcd'
name: 'abcd'
name: 'abcde'
Invalid: '[ name : abcd]'
Invalid: '[ name#abcd]'
```

Comment: For me editing the current matcher is a constraint. also  [ name#abcd] & [      name # ab   ] are valid inputs